# PhantomJS and XPath selectors

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, phantomjs, webdriver-io

I have a `HTML` page which has more than one of the following elements:

```
<div id="asd">
...
   <span id="dfgh">Mytext</span>
...
</div>
```

I use Webdriver-io with the WDIO runner to run jasmine tests.

In my test I wait till the spans are **available/visible**, so that I can check some other elements in the DOM.

```
browser.waitForExist('//span[text()="Mytext"]', 120 * 1000, false);
```

I'm running headless tests with PhantomJS started as standalone with the

```
GhostDriverphantomjs --webdriver=4444 --debug=true
```

and I use selenium started as standalone with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver)
```

to run the tests in chrome and firefox.

I've noticed that the same `.waitForExist` function call in chrome runs fast, but in `PhantomJS` this takes really long and sometimes it timeouts without finding the `element`.

Has anyone noticed similar behavior in `PhantomJS` for `XPath` selectors?

What could be the problem with such a `XPath` selector in `PhantomJS`?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this problem myself, the conclusions that I took away are that when you do:

```
browser.get(url);
```

Selenium waits for an answer from the browser that the page was indeed reached. The `Ghostdriver` in PhantomJS gives the signal earlier returning the source code and taking longer on executing the javascript whereas Chrome or Firefox, the signal is sent and often the dynamically generated content is already available. This is particularly annoying when you have a slow internet connections and want to do cross-browser testing

Don't take my word as a fact though, this "conclusion" came from extensive testing only and are assumptions. I'm not familiar with the tool's code.